# Remote asynchronous execution with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a script on a mac mini server that slowly downloads a multi-gigabyte file. I would like to launch this script via SSH from another (linux) server with `ssh mac-server 'nohup /path/to/script arguments'` but immediately kill the SSH connection as soon as I know that the script has been successfully launched. Once it is launched, the SSH connection doesn't serve any useful purpose, systematically fails somewhere during the downloads, and blocks the execution on the linux server.

I can't just do `ssh -f` or `ssh &` because I need the command to fail on the linux server if the script doesn't launch (or if the mac is not reachable).

Comment: Posted with more details and sample reproduction code on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/524738/remote-asynchronous-execution-with-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been [detailed and anwsered on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/524738/remote-synchronous-then-asynchronous-execution-with-ssh).

To sum up, 2 solutions were found:

1. Use `nohup`  to launch the asynchronous task + close file descriptors:

   ```
   exec 0>&- # close stdin
   exec 0<&- 
   exec 1>&- # close stdout
   exec 1<&- 
   exec 2>&- # close stderr 
   exec 2<&-
   ```
2. Use `screen -d -m` to launch asynchronous task. It can then be checked (with `screen -ls`) or reattached at a later time.

Comment: how to quit the within screen if I use the second solution?